# Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'textsize' in package 'android' )

Tags: android, package

Excuse me! Can you help me why had no resource for the "Textsize"?

Thanks you first!

Comment: Post code, layouts and more info if you want to receive help.

Answer (score 2):

It is textSize and not textsize.

```
android:textSize="10sp"
```